# Cannot run web project in openshift

Tags: mysql, openshift

I created a new **Java Web Project**, and deployed it in **Openshift**. But it's not working. Here is status. Someone help me.

> Error: The number of failed attempts to connect to the MySQL server.

My hibernate configuration:

```
<hibernate-configuration>

   <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/Data_web</property>
        <property name="connection.username">OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME</property>
        <property name="connection.password">OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>

        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Mapping files -->

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Is that literally what your configuration file looks like? Or did you replace the connection values with placeholders like OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST before posting your question? If that is what your config file looks like then you aren't using the environment variables properly. You might want to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940467/how-can-i-using-openshift-environment-variables-in-hibernate-cfg-xml

Comment: No, I use this file to deploy and it's not work. "you aren't using the environment variables properly" i'm not really get it. Please explain it for me. I'm newbie and i don't know why. You see my database, and it's different from my app name. Is that problem ?
Thank for your respond

Comment: Hibernate doesn't know it needs to replace OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD with your actual password, etc. Try looking at the question I linked.

Comment: Oh thank you, I solve it. But it still get error 404. "The requested resource is not available".
I created project, added war file to webapps, use git commit and git push.  Did I miss something ?

Comment: Is your server binding to the correct port? Are there any errors in your logs? It could be 100 different things. You need to look at the web server logs, and if you are running a scalable application also look at the HAProxy logs.